# WizardForm - different form for second step

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have implemented the Django WizardForm.

This is how I initialize it:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

 url(r'^advertisement-add/$', 
     AdvertisementWizard.as_view([VenueForm,AuthenticationForm]),
     name='advertisement_add'),
```

In the first step, a user can create an advertisement entering data like city, name etc

And as you can see, in the second step I am asking the user to login in order to process his advertisement.

What I want to do is that if the user is already authenticated, then in the second step I want to pass the form called `UserForm` which is a simple `ModelForm` with `class=User`. Because it is useless to ask the user to login again. And furthermore, my Form Wizard needs a form for its second step.

What I tried but does not work is this:

```
class AdvertisementWizard(SessionWizardView):
    ....

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        if step == '1' and self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = self.request.user
            return UserForm(initial={
                'first_name': user.first_name,
                'last_name': user.last_name,
            })
        return super(AdvertisementWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
    ....
```

This is rendering my `UserForm` just finein the second step, but when I click submit(wizard's default proceed button), the `AuthenticationForm` is rendering complaining about `required_fields` errors

Is there a way to hack this and achieve my goal?
Thanks

Comment: You have passed initial data to `UserForm` and think that `AuthenticationForm` will validate that data ? 0o

Comment: I think has nothing to do. The GET request on the second step works fine filling the ``UserForm`` with initial data. It fails when I submit, Django is considering that the introduced data is actually for ``AuthenticationForm``

Comment: Maybe you should use another form (with excluded some fields) than`AuthenticationForm` in your second case, or if it is modelform you may use `modelform_factory()` and generate what you want, or if you use crispy-forms then on your template you can switch formhelpers to render your form ...

Comment: @MihaiZamfir You need to define all forms for the wizard to work properly, since it validates form data on each step, it needs to know about form fields at all time. The way you can go around this is to define both forms (Auth and User) and use wizard's [skip feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps) and put your `is_authenticated` logic in there.

Comment: @mariodev yep, this trick worked